# div container larger than image inside

Tags: css

once again was hoping you could help me out.

I am a novice at css and trying to build something simple, but even simple is turning out to be really difficult :(. been at this problem for like an hour now.

any ways the problem I have right now is that I have a div that has an image inside, but the div has like 5px space extra at the bottom which I just cannot figure out how to remove.

basically this is what I have

[image]

as you can see there is a little "white" space below the image.

this is what I want (edited using paint)

[image]

basically I have a gray background for body, with a wrapper inside with a width of 70%,

inside the wrapper there is a menu (the little red thing is part of that menu), then there is a div (id=container) whos background is white, width is 142.8571%, and left is 15% so that it covers the whole page. then inside this div is the image.

so basically the problematic div is the div with ID container.

this is my code for the relevent part

HTML:

```
<div id="container">

    <img id="banner-img" src="img/banner.jpg">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{

    background-color: white;

    padding-bottom:0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;


    width: 142.8571%;

    position:  relative;
    left: -21.428571%;




}

#banner-img{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    width: 70%;
    left: 15%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    position: relative;

}
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

now used to this

```
img, #banner-img{
vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: THANKS MAN. its soo annoying to find out that the fix was so simple. if you dont mind, can you explain why this fixes the problem?

Comment: because  img tag in inline-block element and inline-block element is by default vertical-align middle than we do  all inline-block give  to vertical-align:top

Answer (score 35):

Another solution would we to set the image to `block`:

```
img { display: block; }
```

Comment: yup that works. thanks.. If you dont mind can you explain why that worked (since im learning css and want to know why these things happen :) )

Comment: Same reason as [@Rohit Azad states](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447707/div-container-larger-than-image-inside/11447770#comment15106799_11447727).

Comment: @death_relic0 The technical explanation can be found in  the W3 spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-model; A good summary with a whole bunch of workarounds can be found here: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 1):

The blank space at the bottom is probably down to the CR/LF between your image tag and end div tag. Some browsers don't like this. There's probably a CSS workaround, but I tend to remove the CR/LF's and put it all on one line, like this:

```
<div id="container"><img id="banner-img" src="img/banner.jpg"></div>
```

Comment: This is not a browsers problem. This behavior is mentioned in the CSS specification; white spaces between inline elements are always displayed. The workaround is mentioned by PeeHaa: set the element to `display: block;`.

Comment: So removing the whitespace between inline elements should also work. Some browsers do indeed have problems rendering CSS correctly, especially older ones. The only thing that has reliably worked for me in all browsers is to remove the whitespace.

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't use that as a workaround because the HTML may be generated by a JS text editor like TinyMCE – where you haven't full control over the markup. I would use some CSS workaround instead.

Comment: True, but it's an option if it isn't